# Is it possible to fetch HTTP headers only and do not download the content body with Axios in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, http, axios

I have a use-case when I need to check whether an HTTP resource is available (returns HTTP 200) but I don't want to download the response body because it might be large and my monthly transfers are limited.

In C# HttpClient there is an option `HttpRequestOptions.ResponseHeadersRead = 1` that does exactly that.

I'm wondering if this can be done in NodeJS, preferably using the `axios` library? My only idea is to set the `maxContentLength`:

```
axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://<any-url>/',
    maxContentLength: 1000,
})
```

– but I don't like this idea because it's a hack and semantically wrong and sizing the maxContentLength parameter may cause a regular HTTP 404 to end up as a content too large - my code would incorrectly assume that the resource is available but too large.

Comment: Does the target server support the [HEAD method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD)?  That's what it is designed for.  If not and you're using an http request library that lets you get a little lower level, you can read the headers and then drop the connection before reading the body. That would be a hack because the server will be trying to send the body and will likely prematurely see the connection drop (probably logging a connection error).  And, some of the data may be sent anyway into the OS receive buffer, even if you don't read it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

var apiUrl = 'https://api.domain.com/v1/products/'

```
axios.head(apiUrl)
  .then((data) => {
  console.log('data', data.status)
})
  .catch((e) => {
  console.log('error', e)
})
```

Instead of **GET** request, you can use **HEAD** request and you will get the necessary status code with headers information containing content-length, content-type.